# Set mysql Zero date results to null or a blank string

Tags: mysql

I am using str_to_date() as part of an insert command on a field which either contains a correctly formatted date or a blank string.

For rows with a blank string str_to_date returns a ZERO date of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as expected.

I can use the IGNORE keyword as part of the INSERT statement to prevent errors, but having the ZERO date in the table leads to issues later when attempting to compare the field to other vales. My goal is to insert either a blank string or a null value. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What type is the column in your database?  If it's a `DATETIME`, then you cannot store a blank string.  (Also, do you allow `NULL` values in that field?)  What "issues" are you having with comparing?  You're probably doing something wrong there.

Comment: You can probably do something like `NULLIF(str_to_date(''), '0000-00-00 00:00:00')`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be like this:

```
insert into mytable
select
  case
    when varchar_date != '' then str_to_date(varchar_date, 'date_format')
  end as date_column,
  ...
from
  ...
```

(whenever varchar_date is not empty, call str_to_date function which will return a valid date if varchar_date is a valid string, and whenever it is empty just return null)